# I can't test PHP in nginx

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I have problems with Nginx and PHP. For requirements for the course I can not use installers to use Wemp (nginx, php and mysql). I should clarify that the service works correctly MySQL.

I just want to try this simple code, hello.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Prueba de PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body> 
  <?php
 $cadena = 'Hola mundo';
 echo $cadena; 
 ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

WEMP use to start the next start-nginx.bat

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Starting WEMP - Nginx, PHP and MySQL

C:\utils\nginx-1.4.4\nginx.exe

C:\utils\php-5.4.22-Win32-VC9-x86\php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c C:\utils\php-5.4.22-Win32-VC9-x86\php.ini

net start mysql

EXIT
```

nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80

        location ~ \.php$ {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000


        root c:/utils/nginx-1.4.4/html/;

        location ~ \.php$ {     
          fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
          fastcgi_index  index.php;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          include        fastcgi_params;
        }



        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

it may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment these lines in your nginx.conf and restart WEMP

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
}
```